# How to setup MongoDB authentication just like atlas do

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have to setup to host mongodb database in my server and connect through db uri just like atlas i.e.

```bash
mongodb://<uname>:<password>@ip_addr:27017
mongodb://<uname>:<password>@ip_addr:27017/admin
mongodb://<uname>:<password>@ip_addr:27017/test
mongodb://<uname>:<password>@ip_addr:27017/any_database
```

I tried to setup authentication by enabling the authorization in `/etc/mongod.conf` configuration file.

```bash
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Before enabling the authorization I tried creating a superuser for root (all privileges granted) access to database. To do this I ran these commands...

```bash
> mongosh
> use admin
> db.createUser({user:"root",pwd:"pass1234",roles:["root"]})
```

Restarted the mongod service `systemctl restart mongod`

I am able to enable the auth for database but I am only able to connect only these db uris

- `mongodb://root:root1234@ip_addr:27017`
- `mongodb://root:root1234@ip_addr:27017/admin`

But not able to connect these uris (got authentication error)

- `mongodb://root:root1234@ip_addr:27017/test`
- `mongodb://root:root1234@ip_addr:27017/any_database` (if not exist create this db just like atlas becoz root user have permission to create Any Database)

What I am doing wrong in creating the superuser (root user). I tried adding more roles like `userAdminAnyDatabase`, `dbAdminAnyDatabase`, `readWriteAnyDatabase` and didn't mention any specific db name but when I run `db.getUsers()` I got all the users are being attached to admin database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Is not recommended to use the root user for another database, I make de following when I need to connect create a database with authentication:
1.Create root user for admin database

```
db.createUser({
  user: "root", pwd: "yourPass", 
  roles: [ 
    { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
    "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
})
```

2. Switch to new database

   use newDatabaseName
3. Create user

   db.createUser(
   {
   user: "yourUserHere",
   pwd: "yourPass",
   roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "newDatabaseName" } ]}
   )
4. then you must allowed to make authentication at the new database with user added.

   mongosh -u user -p passord --authenticationDatabase yourDatabase

Comment: Did not work, when I try to connect using any db name which is not created it did not connect (it should automatic create db if not exist and then connect). throws authentication error (it should not user has all the permissions). `DB_URI=mongodb://user:pass@ip_addr:27017/mydb`

Comment: Yes, we can explicitly create new user for myDb, and only can authenticate and connect to `<dburi>/myDb` DB_URI, but the aim is to create any db by specifying in the db url and db should automatic create if not exist, just like atlas (we create root user and password then we can connect and create any db by just specifying in the url (db defaults to test db).